# plot data points on googlemap in R

Tags: r, google-maps, twitter, plot

I extracted tweets from twitter using searchtwitter function and created a csv file containing the columns "longitude" and "latitude" and I created a variable "tweets" to read the csv file. Each tweet/row has longitude and latitude data. I want to plot the location of the tweets onto the google map of Singapore.

How do I plot the points on the google map that I created using PlotOnStaticMap function? This is the code to achieve my google map:

```
sgmap<-GetMap(center="Singapore",zoom=11)
PlotOnStaticMap(sgmap)
points(tweets$longitude,tweets$latitude,col="red",cex=.6)
```

I've also tried this code:

```
sgmap<-GetMap(center="Singapore",zoom=11)
PlotOnStaticMap(sgmap,cex=.6,col="red",FUN=points,add=F)
points(tweets$longitude,tweets$latitude,col="red",cex=.6)
```

and:

```
sgmap<-GetMap(center=c(1.352083,103.8198),zoom=11,destfile="map.png",maptype="satellite")
PlotOnStaticMap(lat=tweets$latitude,lon=tweets$longitude,zoom=11,cex=.6,col="red",FUN=points)
```

Comment: Try `PlotOnStaticMap(sgmap, lat=tweets$latitude, lon=tweets$longitude, col="red",cex=.6)`

Comment: I tried and I got this error: Error in MaxZoom(latR,lonR,size): argument "size" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this task using `ggmap` and `ggplot2`. You download a map using `ggmap` then plot data points on the map using `geom_point` in `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

sing <- get_map(location = "singapore", color = "bw",
                zoom = 11, maptype = "toner", source = "google")

# This is a pseudo tweets data frame including long and lat only
set.seed(12)
foo <- data.frame(long = runif(300, 103.68, 104),
                  lat = runif(300, 1.3, 1.42))

ggmap(sing) +
geom_point(data = foo, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: I got this error: Error in annotate("rect",xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,: unused arguments (xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,fill=darken[2],alpha=as.numeric(darken[1]))

Comment: "Error in annotate("rect",xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,: unused arguments (xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,fill=darken[2],alpha=as.numeric(darken[‌​1]))" I just copied this from the console.

Comment: It may be the case that other R packages are causing this. Would you be able to remove all from your present R session (type `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)`) and restart R? Then, upload `ggmap` and `ggplot2` and see what happens.

Comment: I've restarted R and copied your codes exactly. I still got the same error

Comment: @RachelBoey I have run the code again. But, I do not have any error message. Which version of R and packages do you have? Are they all up to date?

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help but I just ran @Pascal's code and it worked.

Comment: @RachelBoey No problem. Glad to hear that. It's better to stick to what works for you. :)